# How to make Custom Apps Script Function trigger on edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So I created a Custom Google Apps Script project, and then deployed it as an add-on (for my domain only). However I soon realized that I need to change the trigger to be only onEdit. However that option isn't there for this Apps Script project. How do I get around this? In the picture there is only time-based trigger and calendar trigger. While for a script that's not deployed as an add-on there is an option to make it trigger onEdit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using the "add trigger" button on the project triggers page we could only create on edit triggers for Bound to spreadsheet (Google Sheets) projects.

The alternative is to create the trigger by using code. For details please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

---

it's worthy to note that the documentation in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview on the Types of Scripts lists three

- Standalone
- Bound to G Suited Documents
- Web Apps

In this case the screenshot that is included in the question corresponds to a **standalone** project.

Comment: Thank you for the info. One thing I am still confused about. Where does the triggers.gs file go? Alongside the Code.gs file or? @Rubén

Comment: Create a `triggers.gs` file is optional as you could add the code on `Code.gs` or whatever the file is named, in other words how you organize your project is a matter of style (note some features like parenthesis match highlighting doesn't work on large files, the browser could freeze when loading too large files, etc.)